# Changing the nginx fcgiwrap user

Tags: shell, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to use fcgi with a shell script and make it callable via nginx.
No matter what I do though, the script is ran with www-data user. I need it to run as `nginx` user that nginx is using.

nginx 1.15.1
Installed fcgiwrap:
`apt get install fcgiwrap`

Config is following:
nginx.conf:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
http {
 location ~ (\.sh)$ {
            gzip off;
            root /home/nginx/www;
            autoindex on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/nginx/www;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/nginx/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

The problem I need to fix is access to some of the files other scripts have created that run under nginx user.

I also tried editing `/etc/init.d/fcgiwrap` to change

```
FCGI_USER="nginx"
FCGI_GROUP="nginx"
# Socket owner/group (will default to FCGI_USER/FCGI_GROUP if not defined)
FCGI_SOCKET_OWNER="nginx"
FCGI_SOCKET_GROUP="nginx"
```

But it had no effect. The script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo 'Content-Type: text/plain'
echo ''
echo $(whoami)
echo $(groups)
```

The output is:

```
www-data
www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the path to the **fcgiwrap.service** file:

`systemctl status fcgiwrap.service`

[image]

2. Change the **User** and the **Group** in **fcgiwrap.service** file:

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/fcgiwrap.service
```

[image]